# Changing column value based on part of a string in another column in R

Tags: r, string, replace, row

I'm new to R so please bear with me! I Have a dataframe named `mydata`. Here's a sample of the relevant columns:

```
Backlog.Item.Type       Description
Feature                  Assignment 1  
Product Backlog Item     As a user I want to                                                           
Task                     Do this
```

Now, what I want to accomplish is the following: if part of the string in `Description` matches 'As a' or 'As an', I want to replace that rows value for the `Backlog.Item.Type` column with the string 'User Story'. To select these rows, I use

```
x <- mydata[grepl("As a", mydata[["Description"]]) | grepl("As an", mydata[["Description"]]), ]
```

However, I do not know how to then replace the corresponding value in the `Backlog.Item.Type` column. It is probably pretty simple to do this, but any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance, I hope I have been clear enough and formulated my question in an understandable manner!

Answer (score 0):

I guess there will be a more elegant solution, nevertheless this will do the trick:

```
    library(stringr)
df=tibble(Backlog=c("Feature","Product","Task"),Description=c("Assignment 1","As a user i want to","Do this"))
matches<-c("a user","an user")
matchTable=sapply(matches,function(x) str_detect(df$Description,x))
rows=sapply(1:nrow(df),function(x) any(matchTable[x,1],matchTable[x,2]))
df$Description[rows]='User Story'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
  mutate(
      Backlog.Item.Type = case_when(
        str_detect(mydata$description, "As a") | str_detect(mydata$description, "As an") ~ "User Story",
        !(str_detect(mydata$description, "As a") | str_detect(mydata$description, "As an"))) ~ Backlog.Item.Type
      )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dom! When I try this solution, I get the following error: `Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, col, value = case_when(str_detect(mydata$Description,  : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 2698` Do you have any idea why?